# neo4j: type counts by distance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to have some count statistics by type by distance from root. For example,

(A type:'private')-[value:20]->(B type:'private')-[value:40]->(C type:'private')

(A type:'private')-[value:0]->(D type:'public')-[value:20]->(E type:'private')

```
CREATE (:firm {name:'A', type:'private'}), (:firm {name:'B', type:'private'}), (:firm {name:'C', type:'private'}), (:firm {name:'D', type:'public'}), (:firm {name:'E', type:'private'});
MATCH (a:firm {name:'A'}), (b:firm {name:'B'}), (c:firm {name:'C'}), (d:firm {name:'D'}), (e:firm {name:'E'})
CREATE (a)-[:REL {value: 20}]->(b)->[:REL {value: 40}]->(c),
(a)-[:REL {value: 0}]->(d)->[:REL {value: 20}]->(e);
```

I want to get the count of each type of A's immediate neighbors and that of the 2nd layer neighbors, i.e.,

```
+-----------------------------+
| distance |   type   | count |
+-----------------------------+
| 0        |  private |   1   |
| 0        |  public  |   0   |
| 1        |  private |   1   |
| 1        |  public  |   1   |
| 2        |  private |   2   |
| 2        |  public  |   0   |
+-----------------------------+
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69923170/neo4j-aggregate-function-by-distance/70347082?noredirect=1#comment124461733_70347082) is a related question about aggregate statistics by distance.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this on, the [apoc library](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/) comes in handy:

```
MATCH path=(:firm {name:'A'})-[:REL*]->(leaf:firm)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:REL]->(:firm)
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths, max(length(path)) AS longest
UNWIND RANGE(0,longest) AS depth
WITH depth,
     apoc.coll.frequencies([node IN apoc.coll.toSet(REDUCE(arr=[], path IN [p IN paths WHERE length(p) >= depth] |
                                   arr
                                   + nodes(path)[depth]
                            ) 
     ) | node.type
     ]) as typesAtDepth

UNWIND typesAtDepth AS typeAtDepth
RETURN depth, typeAtDepth.item AS type, typeAtDepth.count AS count
```

for this dataset

```
CREATE (_174:`firm` { `name`: 'A', `type`: 'type2' }) CREATE (_200:`firm` { `name`: 'D', `type`: 'type2' }) CREATE (_202:`firm` { `name`: 'E', `type`: 'type2' }) CREATE (_203:`firm` { `name`: 'F', `type`: 'type1' }) CREATE (_191:`firm` { `name`: 'B', `type`: 'type1' }) CREATE (_193:`firm` { `name`: 'C', `type`: 'type2' }) CREATE (_174)-[:`REL` { `value`: '0' }]->(_200) CREATE (_200)-[:`REL` { `value`: '20' }]->(_202) CREATE (_202)-[:`REL` { `value`: '99' }]->(_203) CREATE (_174)-[:`REL` { `value`: '20' }]->(_191) CREATE (_191)-[:`REL` { `value`: '40' }]->(_193)
```

it returns this result:

```
╒═══════╤═══════╤═══════╕
│"depth"│"type" │"count"│
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│0      │"type2"│1      │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│1      │"type2"│1      │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│1      │"type1"│1      │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│2      │"type2"│2      │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│3      │"type1"│1      │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Geez! Thank you so much neo4j expert. How did you learn about this? I do not see it in the documentation. (By the way, your product looks fantastic!)

Comment: @cccfran Thanks for your kind words. FYI everything is in the Neo4j documentation. It's worthwhile to spend some time browsing the apoc docs. Did you use our product already? I can give you a spin if you reach out directly.